# How would you input xkcd.com/287 into WolframAlpha?

Tags: combinatorics, np-complete, wolfram-alpha, popular-math

In [this XKCD comic](http://xkcd.com/287), a stick figure asks an NP-complete problem to order exactly `15.05` worth of appetizers out of a menu that includes the following list of prices: `{2.15, 2.75, 3.35, 3.55, 4.20, 5.80}`.

What is the mathematical name and procedure for this kind of problem, and how would you input something like this to WolframAlpha if possible?

[image: NP-Complete: General solutions get you a 50% tip.]

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: I think this question is ok. Please consider this comment a vote against closing it.

Comment: i couldnt get the joke in the xkcd link apparently :(

Comment: Rather unfortunately, `.01*IntegerPartitions[1505, All, {215, 275, 335, 355, 420, 580}]` doesn't work in Alpha.

Comment: The stick figure poses an *instance* of an NP-complete problem. NP-completeness is a property of problems (which in complexity theory is synonymous with *classes* of problems), not of problem instances. For every problem instance, there's a trivial polynomial-time algorithm to solve it, namely the one that simply prints the solution.

Comment: @joriki: Did you intend to write "which in complexity theory is synonymous with classes of problem instances"?

Comment: @Srivatsan: Ah, yes, that would have been much clearer :-) I guess I meant that "problems" in complexity theory is synonymous with "classes of problems" in everyday language.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To count the number of solutions, enter `series for 1/((1-x^(215/100))(1-x^(275/100))(1-x^(335/100))(1-x^(355/100))(1-x^(420/100))(1-x^(580/100))) at x=0` (or click [here](http://series%20for%201/%28%281-x%5E%28215/100%29%29%281-x%5E%28275/100%29%29%281-x%5E%28335/100%29%29%281-x%5E%28355/100%29%29%281-x%5E%28420/100%29%29%281-x%5E%28580/100%29%29%29%20at%20x=0)), then press "More Terms" about two dozen times until you get the coefficient for $x^{1505/100}=x^{301/20}$, which is $2$, so there are two solutions.

For a slightly smaller problem, you could also get the solutions themselves by entering `series for 1/((1-a x^(215/100))(1-b x^(275/100))(1-c x^(335/100))(1-d x^(355/100))(1-e x^(420/100))(1-f x^(580/100))) at x=0` (or clicking [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series%20for%201/%28%281-a%20x%5E%28215/100%29%29%281-b%20x%5E%28275/100%29%29%281-c%20x%5E%28335/100%29%29%281-d%20x%5E%28355/100%29%29%281-e%20x%5E%28420/100%29%29%281-f%20x%5E%28580/100%29%29%29%20at%20x=0)) and decoding the coefficient of $x^{1505/100}$. Unfortunately Wolfram|Alpha stops offering more terms at $x^{10}$, so the best we can do is to deduce from the coefficient $a^3d+ef$ of $x^{10}$ that there are two appetizer combinations for exactly $\$10$, namely $3$ mixed fruit and hot wings, or Mozzarella sticks and a sampler plate.

To see why this works, you can read up on [the generating function for the partition function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Generating_function).

Comment: SAGE says $(a^7+ad^2f)$ for 15$05

Comment: @Myself: That's a lot of mixed fruit! :-) Thanks!

Comment: @Myself - Nice. In alternative notation, $7a = 15.05$ and $a+2d+f=15.05$, where the letters label the appetizer prices in the order they're given.